# How to filter grand children using EF PLUS

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2, entity-framework-plus

I want get to `Parent` and its only active `Children` and active `Grand Children` using Entityframework Plus

Relationship
Parent -> Children -> GrandChildren

```
var parent = await _dbContext.Parent
             .IncludeFilter(p=>p.Children.Where(c=>c.IsActive == true))
             .IncludeFilter(p=>p.Children.Select(c=>c.GrandChildren.Where(gc=>gc.IsActive ==true)))
             .Where(p=>p.ParnetID == 1234)
             .SingleOrDefaultAsync()
```

The above query does not work. The children does not get filtered. It returns all Children including inactive children. However GrandChildren gets filtered( however i am guessing grand childeren are getting filtered in memory not in sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the filter as well on the Children the second time you use `IncludeFilter`, otherwise, you will include the Children unfiltered.

```
var parent = await _dbContext.Parent
             .IncludeFilter(p=>p.Children.Where(c=>c.IsActive == true))
             .IncludeFilter(p=>p.Children.Where(c=>c.IsActive == true).Select(c=>c.GrandChildren.Where(gc=>gc.IsActive ==true)))
             .Where(p=>p.ParnetID == 1234)
             .SingleOrDefaultAsync()
```

Comment: Thats what i ended up using except you don't need the first filter

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have ended up using. This create 3 sql statements

```
var parent = await _dbContext.Parent
             .IncludeFilter(p=>p.Children.Where(c=>c.IsActive == true).Select(c=>c.GrandChildren.Where(gc=>gc.IsActive ==true)))
             .Where(p=>p.ParnetID == 1234)
             .SingleOrDefaultAsync()
```